# Armature animation is transformed incorrectly and cannot reset to its default position

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, pose-mode

I am not sure what I did, but suddenly my bones in pose mode are no longer the one that I had before. And therefore, all the animations I did before (which were normal) are now weird and distorted.

The bones in edit modes are still the ones that I had before, which is expected as rest pose in pose mode:

[image]

But in pose mode (rest pose), the bones are now like this (Note the foot bone and arms, which is clearly not the same to the ones in edit mode):

[image]

And for animations, the running animation which goes forward is now going backward instead, with a weird animation:

[image]

By the way, here's the same animation which I exported before:

[image]

---

**Additional information**

- No constrains nor modifiers (except mirror and IK) are used.

**What I tried**

- Clear transforms in pose mode
- Applying transforms in object mode
- Re-parent in object mode

**What I guess that is happening**

- I have accidentally applied a position as rest pose (couldn't figure out a button to reset it, however I tried the this process and it modifies the bone in edit mode as well, so I'd discard this possibility)
- I have scaled the armatures and as the animation transforms are not scaled, the animation is distorted (however, it doesn't explain why my character is running backwards nor the weirdness in rest pose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When I was animating I accidentally got into edit mode and pressed ALT-R (thought that I was in pose mode), which reset the roll position of the bones.

Recalculating the roll position brings the bones to the rest position when no transforms are applied.

[image]

However, the animation still has weird behavior, it might be that the recalculated roll is different to what I had when rigging the bones.

Anyway, here's my tip: **RECALCULATE ROLL BEFORE ANIMATING**. So if you accidentally changed the roll, you only have to recalculate the roll and not to reanimate all the animations.

Comment: i have same problem with hot keys and modes